# How do you report percent error with limited precision?

Tags: error, measurement-error, accuracy

Let's say you have an experimental data point with limited precision, such as 0.67 ± 0.1, and a known actual value such as 0.72. What is the standard way to report the percent error in this case, taking the limited precision into account? My best guess is that you would report the percent error with limited precision as well, which would be 13.9% ± 6.94% in my example, but I'm not sure.